# How to create an instance template based upon a deployed VM in YAML/JINJA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, jinja2, google-deployment-manager

I have a basic `.yaml` and `.jinja` deployment set-up for Google cloud, but want to be able to deploy a VM within either `.yaml` or `.jinja` that is based upon a previously deployed VM that was deployed through the Google cloud GUI.

I understand that this could be achieved through an instance template but how would I accomplish this within a `.jinja` / `.yaml` deployment?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered Deployment Manager or Terraform?

Comment: Yes, ideally through google's deployment manager with my deployment script, the problem I am having if finding relevant documentation on how to do this through `.jinja` / `.yaml`

Comment: I've been looking at this piece of documentation from google: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#based-on-existing-instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom image based your VM deployment, and then reference that image in your .jinja / .yaml deployment file.

This link will help you: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image